# module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy)) ImportError: Import by filename is not supported

Tags: python

I am trying to import a variable to my unit test file from another folder in my directory, but I continue to get this error in the terminal "**ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.**" Here is my unit test code:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from models import db, User
from app import create_app, CURR_USER_KEY
from sqlalchemy.exc import InvalidRequestError


class UserViewTestCase(TestCase):
    """Test views for users."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Create test client, add sample data."""
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
```

Here is the code from the file that I am importing from:

```
"""Application."""

from flask import Flask
from models import connect_db
from config import config


app = Flask(__name__)

CURR_USER_KEY = "curr_user"

def create_app(config_name):
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
    connect_db(app)
    return app
```

Here is a photo of how my directory is set up:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to do is an explicit relative import. For that you will need to specify the relative path (e.g., `from .app import create_app, CURR_USER_KEY`)

Comment: thanks for your help, but unfortunately I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Would `import app` (follow by appropriate calls in `setUp` method) suffice for your needs or do you really want to only import what you need?

Comment: I would only like to include the code that is necessary